# Flash reading only certain XML Characters

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I have a dynamic textbox in flash called vt. It has attached to it the following in a class file:

```
vt.text = xml.video.@vt[cv];
```

and pulls the information from an XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<playlist>
    <video src='videos/video1.flv' vt='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'/>
</playlist>
```

Now for some reason only the letters a d g i l n o will actually display when tested with all the alphabet above. Any ideas why on earth this odd thing is happening?

UPDATE: Solved - Just needed to change the textbox AA to Use Device Fonts :) (New user cant answer my own question)

Mark

Comment: Did you check if you embedded the whole font?

Comment: @Malte Kohrer (sorry cant do the cool little o for your name) but thanks you headed me on the right track just needed to change the AA to use device fonts :)

Answer (score 0):

Imho, you don't need to apply [cv] to attribute. If it is video index, you need to apply it to video tag: `xml.video[cv].@vt`

Comment: Hiya that links it fine as did the other method but the letters missing issue is still showing.